# Data not inserting into Firebase Database

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I am tring to insert a record from my react native app to Firebase. 
And my code as follow:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

var React = require('react-native');
var {
  Component,
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableHighlight,
  TextInput,
  ListView
} = React;
var Firebase = require('firebase');

export default class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    var myFirebaseRef = new Firebase('https://test.firebaseio.com/');

    myFirebaseRef.set({
      title: "Hello World!",
      author: "Simon",
      location: {
        city: "Muenster",
        state: "Germany",
        zip: 48155
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('devdacticFirebase', () => devdacticFirebase);
```

However, when I launch the app, the record is not inserting into my Firebase. It never throw me any error message also. Why is it so? Which part am I missing out?

Comment: Your code shows a URL of `https://test.firebaseio.com/`.  Did you put `test` in as a placeholder for posting your question?  If not, replace `test` with your actual Project ID shown in your project settings at the Firebase Console.

Comment: @BobSnyder Yeah I put it as a placeholder and yes, I did replaced it but somehow it still won't work. After I put in the chunk of firebase code as above, when I launch the app, the Expo just stuck at the loading screen with no error message at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing es5 & es6 code. Since you've already import firebase, you don't need to require it.

**REFERENCE**

In ES5, if you use CommonJS standard, the introduction of React package through basic require, the code is similar to this:

```
var ReactNative = require("react-native");

var {Image,Text} = ReactNative;
```

In ES6, the import wording is more standard similar to this:

```
import { Image, Text} from 'react-native'
```

Recently firebase has updated their web SDK, which changed some of its API. The syntax you're using looks like the 2.x API, while the [latest](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#add_firebase_to_your_app) version is pretty different

Please initialize the firebase once the app is loaded (recommend in componentWillMount method) so that you can use it everywhere in the code

```
componentWillMount() {
    var config = {
         "apiKey": "YOUR_API_KEY",
         "authDomain": "YOUR_FB_DOMAIN",
         "databaseURL": "YOUR_FIREBASE_URL",
         "projectId": "YOUR_FB_PROJECT_ID"
    }
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
}
```

**UPDATE**

It is weird when you put firebase set in the constructor. I guess you want to add new record to the firebase, you can use set with push(), this will add new record. Let say you have user table in the database, so :

```
import {TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {

  componentWillMount() {
      var config = {
          apiKey: "...",
          authDomain: "...",
          databaseURL: "...",
          projectId: "...",
          storageBucket: "...",
          messagingSenderId: "..."
        };
      firebase.initializeApp(config);
  } 

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  insert = () => {
      firebase.database().ref('user').push().set({
          title: "Hello World!",
          author: "Simon",
          location: "Germany",
          city: "Muenster",
          state: "Germany",
          zip: 48155
      }, (error) => {
          if (error) {
             console.log(error.message);
          } else {
             // Success
          }
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> this.insert()}>
             <Text>Hello World!</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: So do I put the componentWillMount() inside the constructor part or?

Comment: componentWillMount() is a react native lifecycle method same as constructor(). Place it  outside constructor().

Comment: I see I see thanks so much! I have updated the question, can you help me check which part I did wrongly? Because it still wont work

Comment: I modified your code so that firebase set is called after you click hello world.

Comment: But why is the ')' highlighted in pink color at the second last line of insert

Comment: Sorry, bracket mismatch. Copy back code from my updated answer.

Comment: But do you have any idea why the screen just stuck at 'Made with expo' and load forever?

Comment: Did you comment this line -> //AppRegistry.registerComponent('App', () => App); . Please uncomment it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148844/discussion-between-emma-hannah-and-digit).

Comment: Yeah the bug was due to the imports. import * as firebase from 'firebase'; import React from 'react'; Thanks so much for the helps!